# Can some one explain why I get an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am not new to php, but I find there optional parameters to be a bit ... unique, or maybe its just me.

If I have the following:

```
class SomeClass{
    public function some_method($required_param, $optional_array = array()){
        var_dump($optional_array); exit;
    }
}
```

Then do something like:

```
$test = new SomeClass();
$test->some_method('required', array('optional'));
```

I get back as a `var_dump` `array(0){}`.

I have even tried:

```
$test = new SomeClass();
$array = array('optional')
$test->some_method('required', $array);
```

With the same result. Is it because I am already defining that `$optional_array` is already set as a empty array? I swear this is how you set [optional parameters, according to example 3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) So why is it sticking with the default empty array? why is it not seeing that hey, this is already set.

Comment: Try `var_dump($optional_array);` It is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SomeClass{
    public function some_method($required_param, $optional_array = array()){
        var_dump($optional_array); exit;
    }
}
```

Use `var_dump($optional_array);` not `var_dump($optional_array());`

Comment: So I realized my mistake >.> thank you. And I just tried it. same issue. Do I need to pass in by reference?

Comment: @user3200412 What do you mean by same issue? I've tried your code and it works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your array as if it were a function. So remove the `()` and it will work:

```
var_dump($optional_array);
```

instead of

```
var_dump($optional_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extraneous set of parentheses on your var_dump.  It's trying to call an anonymous function passed in as an array.

Try this:

```
class SomeClass{
    public function some_method($required_param, $optional_array = array()){
        var_dump($optional_array);
    }
}

$test = new SomeClass();
print "one\n";
$test->some_method('required', array('optional'));
print "two\n";
$test->some_method('required');
```

The output on my machine is:

```
one
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "optional"
}
two
array(0) {
}
```